# Posting user's photo and showing in map

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I'm new in the coding world and have been working on an app that uses geolocated photos. My app is strutted in a list with the pictures that would be taken by the camera, the map where the photos would appear and then the camera to take the pictures. I have already set up the CameraService but I can't sort out how to post that photo into the list view and also to attach it to a location on map.

This is my code in the ContentView:

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI




struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
              
            }
            .navigationTitle(":o ! ! !  Treashures !! ! ¡ !")
                
            
            
           
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion)
        
    }
    
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.3879, longitude: 2.16992), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    
    }


struct AddView: View {
    
    @State private var capturedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var isCustomCamaraViewPresented = false
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if capturedImage != nil {
                Image(uiImage: capturedImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            } else {
                Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
                
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    isCustomCamaraViewPresented.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image("cam")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        
                        
                    
                    
                })
                .padding(.bottom)
                .sheet(isPresented: $isCustomCamaraViewPresented, content: {
                    CustomCamaraView(capturedImage: $capturedImage)
                    
                    
            })
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            ListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("cadira")
                    
                        
                       
                    
                       
                }
            
            MapView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("mapa")
                        
                   
                }
            
            AddView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("subir")
                        
                       
                                
                    
                }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

You asked a number of questions in one go, so I will answer a few, and direct you to research others.

Your first main question is essentially how to keep track of the data. In order to keep track of, and pass your data, you need a data model. A data model is a class or struct that keeps the parameters for you. In this case, I have used a class that keeps an array of your data that I modeled in a struct:

```
class Images: ObservableObject {
    //Strictly speaking this class does not have to be Observable or use @Published
    //However, this will make sure the view stays updated with data change
    @Published var items: [ImageData]
    
    init() {
        // This just gives me fake data to use in the map
        items = [
            ImageData(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.380775, longitude: 2.173661), symbolName: "figure.walk.circle"),
            ImageData(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.4036, longitude: 2.1744), symbolName: "building.columns.circle")
        ]
    }
}

struct ImageData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() //Identifiable conformance
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    // You should not be using a full size image from the camera in an annotation
    // var thumbnail: UIImage? // optional because you may not have it immediately
    // var image: UIImage?
    // For purposes of the map demonstration I will be using SF Symbols
    var symbolName: String
}
```

There are many ways to pass this data around your app. I chose to pass it in an `EnvironmentObject` to each of the classes. That is modeled at the end.

One more thing I will answer is displaying your images on the map at a location. When you capture the image, you will need to extract the location from the meta data. You will then create your `ImageData` using that info.

Once you have the data, you would add the data to your map as annotations. So, your original code would change to something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // "Source of Truth"
    @StateObject var images = Images()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ListView()
                .environmentObject(images)
                .tabItem {
                    Image("cadira")
                }
            
            MapView()
                .environmentObject(images)
                .tabItem {
                    Image("mapa")
                }
            
            AddView()
                .environmentObject(images)
                .tabItem {
                    Image("subir")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var images: Images

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}


struct MapView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var images: Images
    
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.3879, longitude: 2.16992), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
            
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: $images.items) { $annotation in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.location) {            Image(systemName: annotation.symbolName)
            }
        }
    }    
}

struct AddView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var images: Images

    @State private var capturedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var isCustomCamaraViewPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```